# how to define a GroupName for Html.RadioButtonfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on an asp.net MVC 4 .but i got confused on how i can specify Group name for a table of Radio-buttons . so each group of Radio buttons can have on button checked at certian time. I am using `Html.RadioButtonfor`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "group name" is determined by the `name` attribute of the field: all radio buttons with the same `name` attribute value are in the same "group". So, for the purposes of using `Html.RadioButtonFor`, you would just specify the same property for each radio in the group with a unique value for the button, i.e:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.AnimalType, "Cat")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.AnimalType, "Dog")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.AnimalType, "Chicken")
```

Comment: but in you above example all the RadioButton will be on the same Group , which is AnimalType ??

Comment: Yes. If you want some radio buttons to belong to a different group, reference a different property.

Comment: so my question was if the radiobutton use the same attribute name (AnimalType), is there a way to group them in separate groups ?

Comment: No. That's the point. Radio buttons are "grouped" by their `name` attribute. The only way to create a different group is to give it a different name, which means it won't be posted to the other property anymore.