# MVC radio button not selecting alternatively

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, knockout.js

I have implemented two radio buttons in my mvc5 project cshtml page.

While clicking on first radio button it get highlighted but it never get deselected on the click of second radio button. Mean both radio buttons gets highlighted at same time.

**Code:**

```
<div class="panel-content sublevel-2">
                <div class="controls-group">
                    <div class="child min-w200">
                        @Html.KocokeRadioButtonFor(m => m.InvoiceDateType, (int)InvoiceDateType.NextScheduled, new { @cokechecked = true }, new { @id = "txtNextScheduled" })
                        @Html.cokeLabel(RecurringPayableResx.NextScheduled, new { @class = "" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="child">
                        @Html.KocokeRadioButtonFor(m => m.InvoiceDateType, (int)InvoiceDateType.Other, new { @cokechecked = false }, new { @id = "txtOther" })
                        @Html.cokeLabel(RecurringPayableResx.Other, new { @class = "" })
                    </div>
                </div>                    



                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="datepicker-group">
                        @Html.KocokeTextBoxFor(m => m.Data.RunDate, new { @cokeDatePicker = "Data.RunDate", @cokedisable = "Data.IsOtherDateDisabled" }, new { @id = "txtOtherDate", @class = "datepicker default" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>'
```

Thanks for your help!!

```
 <div class="controls-group">
                            <div class="child min-w200">


                                <span class='icon radioBox'><input data-bind="cokechecked:True" id="txtNextScheduled" name="InvoiceDateType" type="radio" value="0" /></span>


                                <label class="" for="">Next Scheduled</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="child">

                                <span class='icon radioBox'><input data-bind="cokechecked:False" id="txtOther" name="InvoiceDateType" type="radio" value="1" /></span>


                                <label class="" for="">Other</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Updating the custom class:

```
 public static MvcHtmlString KocokeRadioButtonFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object value, object koAttributes,
        object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        return RadioButtonHelperFor(htmlHelper, expression, value, koAttributes, htmlAttributes);
    }
```

Below is the custom class called by above class

```
private static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonHelperFor<TModel, TProperty>(HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object value, object koAttributes = null,
        object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        var htmlDictionary = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        var koDictionary = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(koAttributes);
        var control = CommonExtensions.CustomizedDictionary(ControlType.Radio, htmlHelper,
            ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression), htmlDictionary, koDictionary, metadata);
        if (koDictionary.Count > 0)
        {
            var databind = CommonExtensions.GetKoBindings(koDictionary);
            htmlDictionary.Add("data-bind", databind);
        }
        return
            MvcHtmlString.Create(GetSpan(control,
                htmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(expression, value, htmlDictionary).ToHtmlString()));
    }
```

Comment: I have encountered this before, you need to set the name attribute to be the same for each radio button. There is a good explanation on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17702872/how-to-define-a-groupname-for-html-radiobuttonfor

Comment: i checked the html runtime code and it shows name is same ..i will update the code in the same question

Comment: I can see from your code that you are already using the naming conventions correctly. Thats a strange one. Those are custom helper classes you are using right? maybe there is some underlying issue in one of those classes?

Comment: those custom classes are working fine in other pages ..only in this page the issue exists

Comment: In your first radioButton you have set the name to be "txtNextScheduled" but in the second its set to "txtOther" in the third its set to null. Is that intentional? Maybe there is some confliction in this situation

Comment: You should have same name for both the radio button.. Please have a look at the view source, you will get a clue..

Comment: third is not required i removed it .. but still no JOY

Comment: Your raw HTML works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/q2yfemfw/

Comment: So what will be the issues now?

Comment: Maybe posting the "cokechecked" binding handler code